# What is the fastest way to refresh tables in Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, refresh, powerquery

When i try to refresh my Excel Power query, it take ages to refresh and hangs Excel. What is the best way or settings to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The PowerQuery refresh time depends on the data source you are importing. In your case:

1. Limit the number of rows you are importing
2. Put your data in a csv file on your local drive

Comment: Is there a way i can filter the rows before importing into Powerquery

Comment: Sure, simply use DirectQuery mode.

Answer (score 1):

You might explore the use of Table.Buffer and List.Buffer. They can help sometimes.